# Visual Studio Android Intent Class not found

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, android-activity, xamarin.android

I tried to start a new activity with the following code:

```
Intent nextActivity = new Intent(this, typeof(SecondActivity));
StartActivity(nextActivity);
```

When I run the app this error is shown:

> Unhandled Exception: Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException:md55b5ca36da4151fa89622ccc8c5d74c93.SecondActivity

My secondactivity class is this:

```
[Activity(Label = "SecondActivity")]
public class SecondActivity : Activity
{
   protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
      base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
      SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Second);
   }
}
```

I have no clue why this error occures. Several video tutorials doing it the same way and it works but not for me.
Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated

Comment: See https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/xamarin.android_8/xamarin.android_8.1/#Known_Issues

Comment: Delete the bin and obj file in your solution, restart your Visual Studio and try again.

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT I haven't really solved the problem. But I found some information about this problem. It seems to be a problem which occures in the latest update of xamarin android and the developers try to fix it. In some projects the code works, in others it don't. I switched to Android Studio now, because there it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Xamarin.Forms, then in your Droid Project look for the `MainActivity.cs`.

Write the code as follows:

```
Intent service = new Intent(Forms.Context, typeof(SecondActivity));
context.StartService(service);
```

If this does not work, you can still put breakpoint on the above line and debug what is wrong.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I use the Android.Content for this. I just created a second project and there the code works perfectly. I also deleted the SecondActivity and created a new one. This time the extend thing ": Activity" is gray not green like it shoud be and all the methodes like SetContentView are unknown to VisualStudio. And in the SolutionExplorer you normaly have a little arraow to expand the list of a class. This one is missing for my SecondAcitivty. Might that be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In order for the application to run you need to set the Minimum Android Version and the target Android Version in the Android Manifest.

I used the Use Compile using SDK version and it worked for me.[Andriod Manifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vq4fn.jpg)